# How to limit JProfiler to a subtree

Tags: jprofiler

I have a method called com.acmesoftware.shared.AbstractDerrivedBean.getDerivedUniqueId(). When I JProfiler the application, this method, getDerivedUniqueId(), is essentially buried 80 methods deep as expected. The method is invoked on behalf of every bean in the application. I'm trying to record CPU calltree starting with this method down to leaf node (ie, one of the excluded classes).

I tried the following but it didn't produce the expected outcome:

1. Find a method above the method targeted for profiling, eg, markForDeletion().
2. set trigger to start recording at getDerivedUniqueId()
3. set trigger to STOP recording at markForDeletion()

I was expecting to only see everything below markForDeletion(), but I saw everything up to but not INCLUDING getDerivedUniqueId(), which is the opposite of my intended goal. Worse yet, even with 5ms sampling, this trigger increased the previous running time from 10 minutes to "I terminated after 3 hours of running". It seems the trigger is adding a giant amount of overhead on top of the overhead. Hence, even if I figure out how to correctly enable the trigger, the added overhead would seem to render it ineffective.

The reason I need to limit the recording to just this method is: When running in 5ms sampling mode, the application completes in 10 minutes. When I run it in full instrumentation, I've waited 3 hours and it still hasn't completed. Hence, I need to turn on full instrumentation ONLY after getDerivedUniqueId() is invoked and pause profiling when getDerivedUniqueId() is exited.

-- Updated/Edit:
Thank you Ingo Kegel for your assistance.
I am likely not clear on how to use triggers. In the code below, I set triggers as shown after the code. My expectation is that when I JProfile the application (both sampling and full instrumentation) with the below configured triggers, if boolean isCollectMetrics is false, I should see 100% or 99.9% of cpu in filtered classes. However, that is not the case. The CPU tree seems not to take into account the triggers. 
Secondly, when isCollectMetrics is true, the jprofiler call tree I expect would start with startProfiling() and end at stopProfiling(). Again, this is not the case either.

The method contains() is the bottleneck. It eventually calls one of 150 getDerivedUniqueId(). I am trying to pinpoint which getDerivedUniqueId() is causing the performance degradation.

```
public static final AtomicLong doEqualContentTime = new AtomicLong();
public static final AtomicLong instCount = new AtomicLong();

protected boolean contentsEqual(final InstanceSetValue that) {

    if (isCollectMetrics) {

        // initialization code removed for clarity
        // ..........
        // ..........

        final Set<Instance> c1 = getReferences();
        final Set<Instance> c2 = that.getReferences();
        long st = startProfiling();    ///  <-------  start here
        for (final Instance inst : c1) {
            instCount.incrementAndGet();
            if (!c2.contains(inst)) {
                long et = stopProfiling();    ///  <-------  stop here
                doEqualContentTime.addAndGet(et - st);
                return false;
            }
        }

        long et = stopProfiling();    ///  <-------  stop here
        doEqualContentTime.addAndGet(et - st);
        return true;
    } else {
        // same code path as above but w/o the profiling. code removed for bravity.
        // ......
        // ......
        return true;
    }
}

public long startProfiling() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}

public long stopProfiling() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}

public static void reset() {
    doEqualContentTime.set(0);
    instCount.set(0);
}
```

The enabled triggers:
[image]

startProfiling trigger:
[image]

stopProfiling trigger:
[image]

I've tried 'Start Recordings' or 'Record CPU' buttons separately to capture the call tree only
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the overhead with instrumentation is large, you should refine your filters. With good filters, the instrumentation overhead can be very small,

As for the trigger setup, the correct actions are:

1. "Start recording" with CPU data selected
2. "Wait for the event to finish"
3. "Stop recording" with CPU data selected

Comment: Hi. I'm not clear about your suggestion. Isn't the steps above similar to what you are suggesting. Can you provide detailed steps to narrow down the instrumentation to only the calltree starting with getDerivedUniqueId() and have the task complete in a reasonable time. Thanks.

Comment: So do you have the exact actions in your trigger as I suggested? I don't see that in your screen shot. I did provide detailed steps for what you want to do. Improving your filters is not something I can do without detailed knowledge about your application.

Comment: Hi Ingo. Thank you for the help. I've updated the question to include the code and JProfiler snapshot. I can not include the call tree as it is company proprietary.  Can I email/skype you the jprofiler call tree screenshot? Thank you.

Comment: No, all three actions that I mentioned must be in the same method trigger for the root of your measurement, not in separate triggers.

Comment: If both stopProfiling() and startProfiling() methods are in the same trigger and the action page contains both start and stop, there is no way to associate the stopProfiling() with the stop action and likewise for startProfiling. Are you implying that the order of the methods in the specify method page is correlated to the order of the actions in the actions page when creating a trigger?

Comment: It seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding of JProfiler. The application is extremely complex (hence noisy). I simply need JProfiler to start collecting CPU profiling after it enters startProfiling() and stops collecting after it exists stopProfiling(). These two methods are being called over 550million times during the ~200second invocation. Can you confirm whether this is possible in JProfiler?

Comment: That is an extremely fine-grained entry/exit point and will lead to high overhead if instrumented that way. The whole trigger/measurement code will be way to heavy in this case. You should choose the low-overhead sampling mode for CPU profiling and forget about the triggers.

Comment: Hi. Your assessment is exactly what the application is manifesting. I have been sampling the application at 5ms and 1ms for many weeks. Unfortunately, in the ~50 profiles, none of them were able to pinpoint the offending method, that is, the profile was able to go down as far as contentsEqual() then contains() (shown in above code) but no further. Hence, I have been experimenting with full instrumentation but encountering high overhead: I terminated the application (ie, profiling) after ~2 hours of full instrumentation because the call tree had not gotten to the contentsEqual() bottleneck.

Comment: But that means that is no specific bottleneck below contentEquals that is part of the profiled classes (the classes included by your filter settings), otherwise it would show up.